# Text to columns function not working properly?

Tags: excel, vba

I´ve this simple text inside a cell - this is an example of many with the same issue - and I need to put that into columns, delimited by spaces. 
When I do that, the function just do the work with the first sentence, finishing in "deck", and stops there so I´m loosing half of my information or more If I´ve more lines. 
I can´t understand why it´s happening, and I worked for hours on a macro that depends on this information as I wrongly assumed this would be plain easy.

```
      ($94.52) Hold revenue. Need to set up deck.


      ($10.89) Hold revenue. Need to contact purchaser.
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What does the function do and can it differentiate between a space and a carriage return?

Comment: Delimited by spaces?  Your first line would be chopped into 7 different cells.  Are you actually trying to split by line (carriage return)?

Comment: @barryleajo, it´s the function "text to column" you can find in Excel 2010-13 in Data menu. I can´t find an option to delimit by carriage return so I guessed It´d separate the words as if there was nothing in the middle, not just cut the process there.

Comment: @Dave.Gugg, I´m trying to separate based on both spaces and carriage returns.

Comment: Nevermind, I got this! There´s a field for "other" separators. There I tried Ctrl+J which is the carriage return and it works now.

Comment: @pnuts, could be for that example, but I¨ve thousands of fields so spaces and carriage returns are better.

Comment: @pnuts here you are :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got the answer so I´ll post it myself.

I need to separate based on spaces and carriage returns, but I was just trying with spaces thinking there was no way to add carriage returns as a separator. I was wrong.
When you select the function, you´ve a field called "other". There you need to add "Control + J", which is the shortcut for carriage returns.
With that fix, the result is as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your column is A and starts in row 1, create a second column with the following formula in B1:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10)," ")
```

Copy down the entire B column.  Copy and paste this column as values.
Now use the Text to Columns functionality, but use space as the delimiter.

Comment: Thanks Dave! I found a faster way anyway, that´s using the "other" field and using "ctrl + J" as input referring to carriage returns.